# Contar checkboxes marcados e fazer operação

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho os seguintes códigos: o primeiro checkbox equivale ao adicionais que valem 2 reais e o segundo aos que valem 4 reais.

Adicionais de 2 reais:

```
<input type="checkbox" />Morango
<input type="checkbox" />Ninho
<input type="checkbox" />Uva
```

Adicionais de 4 reais:

```
<input type="checkbox" />Nutella
<input type="checkbox" />Bis
<input type="checkbox" />Kit Kat
```

Por meio de javascript, como posso contar quantos checkboxes foram selecionados nos adicionais de 2 reais e contar quantos foram selecionados no adicionais de 4 reais e somar os resultados das duas contagens?

Obs: Não será necessário codar por mim, basta falar o que posso fazer, mas se quiser, sinta-se a vontade...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode contar simplesmente usando um seletor que selecione os input do tipo checkbox que estejam "checked", assim:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length
```

Acontece que, no seu caso não tem como distinguir entre os checkbox de R$2 e os de R$4, por isso sugiro usar uma classe, ou nome para distingir:

```js
document
  .getElementById("contar")
  .addEventListener("click", function(){
    var doisReais = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="dois"][type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

    var quatroReais = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="quatro"][type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

    var total = (doisReais * 2) + (quatroReais * 4);

    console.log("Total de R$2: " + doisReais);
    console.log("Total de R$4: " + quatroReais); 
    console.log("Total: R$" + total);
});
```

```html
Adicionais de 2 reais:
<input name="dois" type="checkbox" />Morango
<input name="dois" type="checkbox" />Ninho
<input name="dois" type="checkbox" />Uva
<br/>
Adicionais de 4 reais:

<input name="quatro" type="checkbox" />Nutella
<input name="quatro" type="checkbox" />Bis
<input name="quatro" type="checkbox" />Kit Kat

<br />
<button id="contar">Contar</button>
```

Comment: +1 _"...  e somar os resultados das duas contagens?"_ Acho que faltou a contagem total dos reais

Comment: verdade @CmteCardeal, adicionei a soma geral :)

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO!!!! Me ajudou e me ensinou uma maneira simples de se fazer isso. Obrigado!

Comment: @VieiraBraz não esqueça de aceitar a resposta se ela te ajudou :)

Comment: Sou novo nesse site, não sei como fazer isso... Vou estar tentando e procurando